# Step size is effectively zero / Stiff system by NDsolve when the parameter in system of ODEs is varying

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

As a very new user of Mathematica, i keep encountering errors as shown below when i try to solve my systems of ode with `phi1` being value around or greater than 4

> NDSolveValue::ndsz: At x == 0.8250616734460338`, step size is
> effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

```
    (*Version of not transforming a,b,phi*)
    Clear["Global`*"]
    
    (*constants*)
    phi1 = 5; (*error occurs when phi1 is large*)
    KcKbRatio = 2;
    DbDaRatio = 2;
    DcDaRatio = 1;
    Cref = 1;
    lambda = 2;
    CrefLambdaRatio = 1/2;
    aEnd = 0.95;
    bEnd = 0.8;
    cEnd = 0.6;
    alpha = 1 - cEnd*CrefLambdaRatio - 
       KcKbRatio*CrefLambdaRatio/(KcKbRatio + 1)/DcDaRatio*aEnd;
    del = $MachineEpsilon;
    (*sidenotes:when lambda>Cref,graphs tend to look normal*)
    (*the system of ode and bcs*)
    ode1 = a''[x] + 2/x*a'[x] - phi1^2*(1 + KcKbRatio)*Phi[x]*a[x] == 0; 
    ode2 = b''[x] + 2/x*b'[x] + phi1^2/DbDaRatio*Phi[x]*a[x] == 0;
    ode3 = Phi''[x] + 2/x*Phi'[x] - 
        KcKbRatio*phi1^2*CrefLambdaRatio/DcDaRatio*Phi[x]*a[x] == 0;
    ode = {ode1, ode2, ode3};
    bcs = {a'[del] == 0, a[1] == aEnd, b'[del] == 0, b[1] == bEnd, 
       Phi'[del] == 0, Phi[1] == 1 - cEnd*CrefLambdaRatio};
    (*ndsolve*)
    {afunc, bfunc, Phifunc} = 
      NDSolveValue[{ode, bcs}, {a, b, Phi}, {x, del, 1}];
    
    (*Plot*)
    Plot[{afunc[x], bfunc[x], Phifunc[x], 
      KcKbRatio*Cref/(KcKbRatio + 1)/DcDaRatio/lambda*afunc[x] + alpha(*,
      Evaluate[{a[x],b[x]}/.exactsol]*)}, {x, del, 1},
     PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

Previously, I asked a similar question with same ode system in this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264980/stiff-system-suspected-error-under-certain-parameter-values), but to no avail as well. I had also tried transforming the solution term `a`, `b`, `Phi` in my code by using transformation such as `a_transformed = Sqrt[a]` and `a_transformed = Log[a]`, but it failed to work as well. Below is my code with transformation.

```
(*Version of trying to transform a,b,phi*)
Clear["Global`*"]

(*constants*)
phi1 = 12;
KcKbRatio = 2;
DbDaRatio = 2;
DcDaRatio = 1;
Cref = 1;
lambda = 2;
CrefLambdaRatio = 1/2;
aEnd = 0.95;
bEnd = 0.8;
cEnd = 0.6;
alpha = 1 - cEnd*CrefLambdaRatio - 
   KcKbRatio*CrefLambdaRatio/(KcKbRatio + 1)/DcDaRatio*aEnd;
del = $MachineEpsilon;
(*sidenotes:when lambda>Cref,graphs tend to look normal*)
(*the system of ode and bcs*)
ode1 = a''[x] + 2/x*a'[x] - phi1^2*(1 + KcKbRatio)*Phi[x]*a[x] == 0; 
ode2 = b''[x] + 2/x*b'[x] + phi1^2/DbDaRatio*Phi[x]*a[x] == 0;
ode3 = Phi''[x] + 2/x*Phi'[x] - 
    KcKbRatio*phi1^2*CrefLambdaRatio/DcDaRatio*Phi[x]*a[x] == 0;

ode = {ode1 /. {a -> (Exp[A[#]] &), Phi -> (Exp[PHI[#]] &)}, 
   ode2 /. {a -> (Exp[A[#]] &), Phi -> (Exp[PHI[#]] &), 
     b -> (Exp[B[#]] &)}, 
   ode3 /. {a -> (Exp[A[#]] &), Phi -> (Exp[PHI[#]] &)}};
bcs = {A'[del] == 0, A[1] == Log[aEnd], B'[del] == 0, 
   B[1] == Log[bEnd], PHI'[del] == 0, 
   PHI[1] == Log[1 - cEnd*CrefLambdaRatio]};
(*ndsolve*)
{Afunc, Bfunc, PHIfunc} = 
  NDSolveValue[{ode, bcs}, {A, B, PHI}, {x, del, 1}];

(*Plot*)
Plot[{Exp[Afunc[x]], Exp[Bfunc[x]], Exp[(PHIfunc[x])], 
  KcKbRatio*Cref/(KcKbRatio + 1)/DcDaRatio/lambda*Exp[Afunc[x]] + 
   alpha(*,Evaluate[{a[x],b[x]}/.exactsol]*)}, {x, del, 1},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

Comment: I run your code (the first one you show above) on V 13.01 and it works with no errors and no warnings?  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb5fU.png)  Which code are you asking about? The first one or the second one?

Comment: I get `NDSolveValue::ndsz` only with the second code and `NDSolveValue[..]` returns the input: When those two things happen, it's because the shooting method failed. If there is a solution to the BVP, you have to give the method good `"StartingInitialConditions"` (see [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html)). If you have some insight from the problem in which this BVP arises, you might have an idea what a reasonable guess for the `"StartingInitialConditions"` might be.

Comment: @Nasser The first code will have error if phi1 is large, eg: `phi1`> 4. Second code is just the transformation of ODEs of first code.

Comment: @MichaelE2 As i want to determine the effect of phi1 on this system of ODEs, the range of suitable `StartingInitialConditions` would vary for different values of `phi1`. May I ask is it possible to automate the process of solving without encountering this error?

Comment: Try this: Get rid of the derivative BCs and use `Method -> "FiniteElement"` in the `NDSolve` call. -- Does the result look correct?

Comment: @MichaelE2 It is working now with `Method -> "FiniteElement"`, Just to make sure i do it correctly, is this how i impose neumann boundary condition into my ODEs?

`ode1 = a''[x] + 2/x*a'[x] - phi1^2*(1 + KcKbRatio)*Phi[x]*a[x] == 
   NeumannValue[0, x == 0]; 
ode2 = b''[x] + 2/x*b'[x] + phi1^2/DbDaRatio*Phi[x]*a[x] == 
   NeumannValue[0, x == 0];
ode3 = Phi''[x] + 2/x*Phi'[x] - 
    KcKbRatio*phi1^2*CrefLambdaRatio/DcDaRatio*Phi[x]*a[x] == 
   NeumannValue[0, x == 0];
ode = {ode1, ode2, ode3};
bcs = {a[1] == aEnd, b[1] == bEnd, 
   Phi[1] == 1 - cEnd*CrefLambdaRatio}; `